# Can Djago create a database query that returns a dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Can Djago create a database query that returns a dictionary of dictionaries?

The model contains a foreign key. Using these keys, I would like to have the query results sorted out. I would then like to provide these results using a rest framework.

Illustration model:

```py
class Record(BaseModel):

    evse = models.ForeignKey(
        'core.Evse',
        verbose_name=_('EVSE'),
        related_name='record_evse',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    current_rms_p1 = models.FloatField(
        _('Current RMS P1'),
        default=0,
        validators=(
            MinValueValidator(0),
            MaxValueValidator((2**16 - 1) * 0.1),
        )
    )

    current_rms_p2 = models.FloatField(
        _('Current RMS P2'),
        default=0,
        validators=(
            MinValueValidator(0),
            MaxValueValidator((2**16 - 1) * 0.1),
        )
    )

    current_rms_p3 = models.FloatField(
        _('Current RMS P3'),
        default=0,
        validators=(
            MinValueValidator(0),
            MaxValueValidator((2**16 - 1) * 0.1),
        )
    )
```

View:

```py
class RecordListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Record.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecordSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Record.objects.all()
```

How to edit a query to get this result?

```json
{
    "evse 1": [
        {
            "current_rms_p1": 0.0,
            "current_rms_p2": 0.0,
            "current_rms_p3": 0.0
        },
        {
            "current_rms_p1": 0.0,
            "current_rms_p2": 0.0,
            "current_rms_p3": 0.0
        }
    ],
    "evse 2": [
        {
            "current_rms_p1": 0.0,
            "current_rms_p2": 0.0,
            "current_rms_p3": 0.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class EVSESerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    record_evse = RecordSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Evse
        fields = '__all__'



class EvseListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Evse.objects.prefetch_related()
    serializer_class = EVSESerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Evse.objects.all()
```

Then add this view to your urls.py etc...

Then when you Evse objects will be serialized, the reports will be serialized too